# How can I use prepared statement with inner sql stament?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

When this is get executed, it throws following exception,
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT travel_manager_id FROM travel_agency_manager WHERE user_id=(SELECT user_i' at line 1"

public class AgencyRegistrationDAOImpl extends DBConnection {

```
public int registerAgency(Agency agency) throws SQLException {

    int returnVal = 0;
    Connection connection = getConnection();

        if (connection != null) {

            String query = "INSERT INTO travel_agency (agency_manager_id,trade_name," +
        "company_name,address,email,city,district,tpno,web_link,description,agency_image_link,business_registration_number" +
        ",isApproved) VALUES " +
        "(SELECT travel_manager_id FROM travel_agency_manager WHERE user_id=(SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email=?)),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";


            returnVal = CRUDOperations.insertAsPreparedStmt(query, connection, agency.getUserName(), agency.getTradeName(),
                    agency.getCompanyName(),  agency.getAddress(), agency.getEmail(), agency.getCity(),
                    agency.getDistrict(), agency.getTelePhoneNumber(), agency.getWeblink(), agency.getDescription(),
                    agency.getImagePath(), agency.getRegistration(), 0);

        }

    return returnVal;
}
```

}

public class CRUDOperations {

```
public static int insertAsPreparedStmt(String query, Connection connection, Object... values) throws SQLException {

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    try {

        if (connection != null) {
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);

            for (int index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
                preparedStatement.setObject(index + 1, values[index]);
            }
            return preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }

    } finally {
        if (!connection.isClosed() && !preparedStatement.isClosed()) {
            preparedStatement.close();
            connection.close();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: What T.J. said. Additionally, this is barely a question, just a code dump.

Comment: I've formatted the code for you and added a missing `;` *(because it seemed extremely unlikely to change the meaning of the question)*, but as HoneyBadger said, this isn't a question. It's unclear how the question in the title applies to the code in the question. You're *already* using a prepared statement in the code.

Comment: You seem to have uncorrected the formatting that someone corrected for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have an error in your SQL syntax

This is not a correct syntax

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES SELECT ....
```

The correct syntax is

```
INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...
```

Here is the [mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

```
INSERT INTO travel_agency (
            agency_manager_id,trade_name, company_name,address,email,city,district,tpno,web_link,description,agency_image_link,business_registration_number, isApproved
    ) 
    SELECT travel_manager_id,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
            FROM travel_agency_manager WHERE user_id=
            (
                SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email=?
            )
```

Comment: I added the missing ) to the statement. But still there is an error,

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT travel_manager_id FROM travel_agency_manager WHERE user_id=(SELECT user_i' at line 1

Comment: @SenalWeerasinghe show the corrected statement please (edit your question with it)

Comment: @SenalWeerasinghe what DB is it ? I have edited my answer since I didn't think before posting the previous.

Comment: It is MySQL version 5.1.39.

Comment: @SenalWeerasinghe check the correct syntax. And of course, update the parameter index since email is at the end now.